# iOS app that checks for duplicate profiles

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I want to create an `iOS` `app` which should load profiles from an `XML` file on the web, check for duplicates and eliminate them. I use `NSXMLParser` to parse the profiles from the `XML` file but now I am confused about how to check for duplicates. The eliminated profiles should be shown in a `UITableView`.

Any idea or help would be appreciated!

```
<profiles>

    <profile>
    <firstname>Amin</firstname>
    <lastname>Ziarkash</lastname>
    <address>Melisstokelaan</address> 
    <zipcode>2541GH</zipcode> 
    <city>DenHaag</city>
    <email>a.ziarkash@hotmail.com</email>
    </profile>

    <profile>
    <firstname>Niko</firstname>
    <lastname>DeVries</lastname>
    <address>Sterrelaan</address> 
    <zipcode>3342JH</zipcode> 
    <city>Amsterdam</city>
    <email>niko@hotmail.com</email>
    </profile>

    <profile>
    <firstname>Marcel</firstname>
    <lastname>Janssens</lastname>
    <address>Voorhoeveweg</address> 
    <zipcode>6006SV</zipcode> 
    <city>Weert</city>
    <email>marcel.j@hotmail.com</email>
    </profile>

    <profile>
    <firstname>Amin</firstname>
    <lastname>Ziarkash</lastname>
    <address>Melisstokelaan</address> 
    <zipcode>2541GH</zipcode> 
    <city>DenHaag</city>
    <email>a.ziarkash@hotmail.com</email>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

Comment: Use `NSSet` for eliminating duplicates.

Comment: @βhargavḯ I understand that NSSet won't display duplicates but what I meant was how to get the profiles within XML shown in an NSArray that NSSet is going to display in the end. Or how do I convert the XML profiles above into an object which I then could use to put in an NSArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this for parsing your XML, once you parsed then filter it accordingly:-

```
-(IBAction)test:(id)sender
{
    self.mutableArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"file:///Users/XYZ/Desktop/test.xml"];//this is your xml file url
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    BOOL par=[parser parse];
    NSLog(@"par=%d",par);
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

          if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstname"])
          {
              self.elementNm=elementName;
          }
         if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"lastname"])
         {
             self.elementNm=elementName;
         }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"address"])
    {
        self.elementNm=elementName;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"zipcode"])
    {
        self.elementNm=elementName;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"city"])
    {
        self.elementNm=elementName;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"email"])
    {
        self.elementNm=elementName;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
          {
              if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"profiles"])
              {
                  NSLog(@"rootelement end");
              }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"\n"].location== NSNotFound)
    {
    if (string.length > 0)
    {
       self.mutableDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [self.mutableDict setObject:string forKey:self.elementNm];
        [self.mutableArr addObject:self.mutableDict];

    }
    }
}

//Now filtered you array after parsing xml
-(IBAction)filterArray:(id)sender
{
    for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in self.mutableArr)
    {
        if ([dict objectForKey:@"zipcode"])
        {
        NSPredicate *pd=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(zipcode == %@)", [dict objectForKey:@"zipcode"]];
         [self.mutableArr filterUsingPredicate:pd];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! Now say if I wanted to have a button to display the profiles from XML in a tableView, each profile in a separate tableViewCel how would I go about that? Check the IBAction (showProfiles) added above.

Comment: You mean to say in each tableview cell you want to display parent to profiles and their children to inside profiles contents??

Comment: Yes that is what I meant.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the xml info inside NSOutlineView? Sorry for bothering but I am new to objective-C.

Comment: Thanks Hussain. IS this the same for iOS? because this is for MAC

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot NSOutlineView is not there in ios. So you have to implement in UITableView only:)

Comment: You just try to implement, If not i will provide you the solution code on monday:)

Comment: Thanks again, really appreciated. Do you maybe have an email or something so I can show you my project, then you would understand what I mean.

Comment: er.hussain52@gmail.com this is my email id

Comment: Thanks, I've sent you the project.

Comment: Thanks amin i got the mail. Will get back to you.:)

Comment: Thank you Hussain! That would be great :)

Comment: Hallo Hussain, did you get any chance to check my project?

Comment: Sorry i did not get chance:(. But once it done will update you for sure

Comment: Ok, thanks :)! I tried to work on it today and for some reason it won't show the profiles in profilesLabel, the label just dissapears

Answer (score 0):

you can use this nice class extension
https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLData:data];
```

You can then map those dictionaries into your own custom class